# Why can't I set z-index through javascript with this function? (I know about camelcase)

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

Hi I want to change the `z-index` of my DOM element, so I used a function to do so. The function works for many properties but not `z-index` I am using Dev Tools and I can see that it is not even being set on the element and I do not know why.

Javascript:

```
    function setStyle(obj, propertyObj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
             if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
                obj.style[property] = propertyObj[property];
            }
        }
    }
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
       setStyle(this, {'zIndex':'-5'}) ;
    };
    img.src = 'test.jpg'
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the good answers.

I was applying a `border` in the CSS code somewhere, so when I was looping through the objects properties `border` was being changed (but the same was not true for `z-index`).

Comment: Um because your running your code all wrong. See answer in a moment

Comment: I literally can't wait.

Comment: I think you could take some time studying what "Own Property" is.

Comment: I think so too. My understanding was that --essentially-- it checks to see if the Object inherits a property or if it directly declared for that object.

Therefore I do not see why a property such as `border` would work but not `zIndex`

Comment: Are you sure the border is not being applied by a css style somewhere?

Comment: Usually to mark the right answer you chose which one you want to use and which is fastest and compliant. You can test at www.jsperf.com if you need.

Comment: Well I am using your answer so congrats there. I really like @Phil's approach using `Object.keys` it is just more thorough than I need here (if there is such a thing?)

Comment: Well thorough is good unless u meant something else. Testing the type is good I just don't you js stock typeof keyword anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well add yet another answer...

```
typeof obj.style === 'object' && Object.keys(propertyObj).forEach(function(key) {
    obj.style[key] = propertyObj[key];
});
```

IMO, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is superior to a `for ... in` loop as it is immune from `Object` prototype injection problems.

This also ensures that `obj` has a `style` property to begin with.

#### Update

Because some people are in to micro-optimisation, here it is without the `Array.forEach`

```
if (typeof obj.style === 'object') {
    var keys = Object.keys(propertyObj);
    for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        obj.style[key] = propertyObj[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer. Thanks for explaining why you chose to use `Object.keys`  One question, from what I am reading, it seems like the `Object` prototype inject is not an issue with the `style` property. Can you confirm this? Also, why the `obj.style` check? This is just to make sure the `obj` has that style?

Comment: Not superior at all like 95% slower actually https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa ... my bad least the forEach js

Comment: @Startec It's only an issue when iterating an object's properties using a `for...in` loop. What can happen is that a separate piece of code might add to the `Object` prototype. Then, all of a sudden, all objects have extra properties that you might not be expecting.

Comment: @EasyBB I only said `Object.keys` was superior to a `for...in` loop and **not** because it's faster

Comment: Lol isnt that what writing in Vanilla JS all about? Speed.

Comment: @EasyBB This **is** vanilla JS. I understand that `Array.forEach` is slower than a `for` loop but I like the readability. Again, I never said this was faster

Comment: I know it is vanilla haha. Im stating while we are using this why not make sure we use compatible fast code as to not hog resources. Unlike the otherhand of jQuery and its three hundred functions of that half are basic duplicates haha. If you understand what im saying. I just like speed worth while coding even if it suffers readability Id still use vanilla of jQuery which is more readable than vanilla to a newcomer rather an experienced js programmer.

Comment: @Phil, in your first answer, do you need to put the `typeof` in a conditional or something?

Comment: @Startec Not sure what you mean. `typeof obj.style === 'object'` **is** a boolean statement (ie, a conditional)

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your first answer, it looks like that belongs in a loop, or is that a loop? (I have just always seen that in an `if...else` format

Comment: @Startec It's what's referred to as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). The statement on the right-hand-side of the `&&` will only be evaluated if the left-hand-side statement is *truthy*

Comment: Is it possible to use the short-circuit evaluation in your final answer?

Comment: @Startec possibly, but it wouldn't make any difference. It's really just syntactic sugar. It works nicely with the first snippet because it's all of two statements.

Answer (score 3):

```
function setStyle(el, propertyObj) {
    for (var property in propertyObj){
          el.style[property] = propertyObj[property]
    }
 }

var img = new Image();
img.onload=function(){
   setStyle(this,{
      'zIndex':"999"
   });
};
```

Comment: I don't see what this changed (other than no longer checking the `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: @Startec This loops over `propertyObj` instead of `obj`

Comment: Um im sorting through the actual property object. You were sorting through `this` the way you wrote it. That is also why I changed your argument names, to better understand. Im on my phone so if there are any spelling errors that's my fault.you should read the code and see the difference between yours and mine. Also you dont need to check hasOwnProperty for styles. If it isnt an acceptable style it won't add it anyways.

Comment: In my defense (if this is one) I copied that code from elsewhere on SO (indefensible). Thank you for this.

Comment: Its ok thats the problem with some of these SO answers ill update when I get time for a computer ha. So for future references it'll help others. Sorry I dont mean to come off rude. Its how I am on my phone um this um that haha

Comment: You should really be checking `propertyObj.hasOwnProperty(property)` to avoid `Object` prototype injection problems.

Comment: I dont check the style because we are setting it for a reason. Itd close to what I have for my library called `mini.js` theres many speed variants in iterators. for loop is slower than a while loop negative iterator. But we use both for different cases. A for in is faster than any other method of js iteration on objects. Ive used it plenty of times for this. If your not opposed to libraries my `mini.js` is literally like 20kb unminified and only has like 10 functions and is only about 10% slower than vanilla unlike  jQuery which is roughly 93% slower. If so I'll let you try it.

Comment: I didn't say *"style"*. Please read the docs for [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) ~ *"If you only want to consider properties attached to the object itself, and not its prototypes, use `getOwnPropertyNames` or perform a `hasOwnProperty` check (`propertyIsEnumerable` can also be used)."*

Comment: No I know Phil I commented after you but was referring to him before lol. My bad. Damn phone is hard to type on

Comment: While we're talking micro-optimisation... Looping over the result of `Object.keys` outperforms `for...in` ~ http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-for-in

Answer (score 0):

```
if(obj.style && obj.style.hasOwnProperty(property)){
    obj.style[property] = propertyObj[property];
}
```

Comment: Needs `for (var property in propertyObj)`

Comment: Isn't this just checking to see if the `Obj` has styling? As I mentioned, this works for some styles but not `z-index`.

Comment: No, this is checking to see if obj.style already has a zIndex set whic h I assume is what you wanted based on your code. If you don't care if it already has it set you can take out the obj.style.hasOwnProperty(property)

Comment: Which is why I removed it from the version I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a z-index with JS is as easy as this:

```
document.getElementById('IDHERE').style.zIndex = "2000";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors:

Your `for in loop` is looping through image object, not the properties object.

Your `hasOwnProperty` check is wrong (and unnecessary). You're checking to see if the obj has your style props, not whether the style object has the style props

It should read:

```
function setStyle(obj, propertyObj) {
    for (var property in propertyObj) {
        obj.style[property] = propertyObj[property];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well put. I seem to be reading conflicting things here. Is the `hasOwnProperty` check necessary?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is necessary when using a `for...in` loop.

Comment: Nope, `style` will ignore any props it doesn't use.